# The application was unable to start correctly (0xc00007b)

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, runtime-error, sfml

I've searched at a lot of places, asked a lot of people, but didn't found an answer to fix this issue..

I've just created a game in C++ with [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) in Visual Studio Community 2015. My project settings are set like they have to (followed [this](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-vc.php) guide).

When I runu the game on my pc, it works totally fine. If it runs on a pc without Visual Studio 2015, it will crash and returns the following error:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc00007b)

I've also downloaded Dependency Walker, to check the .exe on errors and it results a couuple of errors. They can be seen in [this screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/3fb103a5d2efe1e9bfd18cb21bf266d7.png). Sorry for the dutch error after `Error opening file`. It says: `The system can't find the given file`.

These are the dll's I'm icluding in the root folder of my game:

[image: Dll's in my root folder]

I'm hoping you guys can help me out.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you compiled in debug or in release mode ?

Comment: When compiled in debug mode you need the dll's with `-d` suffix, as in `sfml-audio-2-d.dll`.

Comment: I compiled in release

Comment: Add the redistributable package with your installing setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error code rings a bell - have you installed the visual c++ redistributable package on the PCs where VS is not installed? You should be able to find the package in your VS folder (program files).

Comment: Why should people, that want to play a game, have the visual c++ redistributable?

Comment: The redistributable contains libraries which your program may require. Programs will typically install it during their installation process.